# Why is it sometimes difficult to get a receipt for a flight

Tags: air-travel, regulations

Although the majority of flights I book come with a receipt automatically emailed to my inbox, there are still several cases where I am provided with an itinerary but no receipt.  Why would any company do this?  Receipts are frequently needed for reimbursements, and there doesn't seem to be an advantage of not sending one.

One theory is that the many layers of affiliates make tracking the receipt difficult (e.g., a purchase goes through through Kayak then through Travelocity to United).
But even purchases direct from some airlines like JetBlue [send you through hoops to just get a simple receipt](http://help.jetblue.com/SRVS/CGI-BIN/webisapi.dll?New,Kb=askBlue,case=obj%281043%29).  If you call and ask, they are cagey with their response, or offer ridiculous excuses like "people don't need receipts that often".

Is there some nefarious reason they want to make it hard?  Or is it just incompetence?

Comment: Are you booking directly with airlines, or via big-name OTAs (Online Travel Agencies), small OTAs, or bricks'n'mortar TAs?

Comment: Are we talking about reimbursements from the airline, or others (employer, host, insurance body, etc)? Now thinking about it, I've never received a receipt for payment from any airline or TA.

Comment: Perhaps I have a different standard for difficult, but one click from the emailed itinerary or looking up a past flight from your account screens on the website doesn't seem so hard. And I seriously doubt airlines are deliberately making it more difficult to get receipts, as opposed to not expending extra effort to make them easier to retrieve. I have to imagine most corporate travel is booked through corporate portals and travel agents, or charged to a company credit card, not charged to personal cards and then reimbursed.