# How can one get a flight receipt from Priceline?

Tags: air-travel, paperwork

This is a more specific question than [Why is it sometimes difficult to get a receipt for a flight](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46796/why-is-it-sometimes-difficult-to-get-a-receipt-for-a-flight) as it focuses on one specific site, but the premise is the same, and for consistency in this question, assume a JetBlue flight booked through Priceline.  ([JetBlue says](http://help.jetblue.com/SRVS/CGI-BIN/webisapi.dll?New,Kb=askBlue,case=obj%281043%29) you have to get the receipt from Priceline).  **How can one get a receipt?**

Logging in to Priceline, one can go to My Trips, click on a trip to see details, and there's even a top menu item "Print Itinerary and Receipt." However, this link just prints an itinerary listing the travel details and trip **cost**, with no indication or acknowledgement or showing of **payment**.

Comment: What you've described sounds to me like a receipt. There's a description of the services purchased and the cost. Some receipts might include a notation like "VISA" and the last four digits of the credit card number. Does the Priceline receipt not somehow make it clear that it is a receipt and not just a quote?

Comment: The Priceline itinerary does not make it clear that it's a receipt and not just a quote.  
"Some receipts might include a notation like "VISA" and the last four digits of the credit card number." => that's the "acknowledgement/proof of payment" element which is important and missing on their receipts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Priceline has a policy against giving receipts that evidence payment because of how they process payments.
The solution is to request a receipt from an airline agent at the ticket counter or gate, before the flight.

---

*Update: If someone at Priceline reads this, you really should change that.*
[image]

Comment: Do you have a source for this, such as an official statement from Priceline? And any idea why their payment processing method would discourage this?

Comment: The receipt-seeker asked in a chat with an official Priceline representative who repeated the policy multiple times, saying the itinerary is all the receipt they can give.  The rep also said "Priceline only used [authorized] your card to guarantee the reservation for you however, the charge will be charged by the airline."  So if Priceline doesn't actually receive payment directly, that does make it hard for them to issue evidence that they received payment.

Comment: I was able to get it in 2019

Comment: what does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

Team, I was able to get a link in text chat with priceline support *for a hotel receipt*. The format was `https://www.priceline.com/receipt/<64-character hexadecimal number>?offer-token=&csagent=Y#/accept/`. (The hotel I stayed at would not give me the receipt because they said they don't actually have the info i need, ,since I booked with 3rd-party).

Comment: Was that a receipt for a hotel or flight?  Please clarify the answer as it may differ.

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify that even though this question is about a flight receipt, mine was a hotel. (I arrived at this page through my query about hotel receipts, so perhaps my additional answer will help others who find this page similarly). thanks to @WBT for the clarification question.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the [Priceline Find My Trip](https://www.priceline.com/profile/#/checkstatus) screen, enter your email address and Priceline trip number, you should be directed to the receipt screen.

Comment: this did not have the payment information when I tried it (2019)